# IEqualityComparer Not calling subclass in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, iequalitycomparer

I'm trying to implement an IEqualityComparer on a sub class which will be stored as a key to a dictionary.

the following is what i have

```
public class SuperClass : IEqualityComparer<SuperClass> {

    public virtual bool Equals(SuperClass dictKeyComparerA, SuperClass dictKeyComparerB) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual int GetHashCode(SuperClass dictKeyComparer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();    
    }
}

public class SubClass : SuperClass {

    private readonly string application;

    public SubClass(string application) {
        this.application = application; 
    }

    public override bool Equals(SuperClass dictKeyComparerA, SuperClass dictKeyComparerB) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(SuperClass dictKeyComparer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();    
    }   
}
```

and i have the following to try to search the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<SubClass, List<string>> TestDict3 = new Dictionary<SubClass, List<string>>(new SubClass("random"));

    var testKeyb = new SubClass("12345");
    var testListb = new List<string>{"aaaaa"};

    TestDict3.Add(testKeyb, testListb);

    var testKey2b = new SubClass("12345");
    var testKey3b = new SubClass("56973");

    if(TestDict3.ContainsKey(testKey2b)) {
        Console.WriteLine("found testKey2b");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("did not found testKey2b");   
    }

    if(TestDict3.ContainsKey(testKey3b)) {
        Console.WriteLine("found testKey3b");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("did not found testKey3b");   
    }
```

When the code is ran, it returns a not implemented exception because it is calling the super class GetHashCode function instead of the override function.

Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: in your example both the super class and the sub class both throw a not implmented exception

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm, - all your functions call:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Which is why they throw a NotImplementedException...

I just tried some sensible code in the SubClass implementations and it works.

```
 public override bool Equals(SuperClass dictKeyComparerA, SuperClass dictKeyComparerB)
{
    var a = dictKeyComparerA as SubClass;
    var b = dictKeyComparerB as SubClass;
    return a.application == b.application;
}

public override int GetHashCode(SuperClass dictKeyComparer)
{
    return application.GetHashCode();
}
```